# Do the Java platform libraries support https

Tags: java, https, apache-commons

All I need to to do is to connect via https. Must I use commons client for this?

Comment: You can use [`java.net.*`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) stuff, but [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) is more convenient (less verbose/opaque) than it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to, you can use a regular `URLConnection`. Something like this:

```
public class URLConnectionReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                uc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }    
}
```

This may require a bit more work if the site you're connecting to uses a certificate that has not been signed by a well known CA or a self-signed certificate. But this is another story.

Comment: Oh, in real you'd like to take the character encoding from the request header first and then feed it to `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use the URL class and specify an HTTPS url.